# Working with coordinates: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm using swift 2 and I'm trying to implement coordinates into a string.

I imported CoreLocation and the class is a CLLocationManagerDelegate.

When I give the coordinates directly to the string (hardcoded) it works fine but when I run the code below passing var lat and var lon I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on var lat = String(stringInterpolationSegment: locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude)

This is the code I'm using:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

@IBAction func GetWeatherForCurrentLocationClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    // working with fixed location

    // getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=31.8669407442509&lon=34.731625048476&units=metric")

    // throwing an fatal error (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)        

    var lat = String(stringInterpolationSegment: locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude)
    var lon = String(stringInterpolationSegment: locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)

    getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(lat)lon=\(lon)&units=metric")


}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because the `location` is an optional so you have to unwrap it. Using multiple unwrapping in `if let` and optional chaining:

```
if let lat = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude,
       lon = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude {

    getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(lat)lon=\(lon)&units=metric")

}
```

Note: You don't have to convert the location to a `String` in order to use it in a string interpolation.